# How to "translate" this code to WPF

Tags: wpf, multithreading

I move application from WindowsForms to WPF. I have the following code:

```
        if (InvokeRequired)
        {
            Invoke(new Action<Version, Version, XDocument>(ShowUpdateDialog), appVersion, newVersion, doc);
            return;
        }
```

How to write the same code on WPF? Thanks

Comment: What are you trying to do?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You really haven't given enough context here. In the past with Windows Forms, I would check if InvokeRequired is true when I wanted to do something UI related from another thread, the equivalent in WPF is:

```
Application.Current.Dispatcher.Invoke(new Action<Version, Version, XDocument>(ShowUpdateDialog), appVersion,
                                              newVersion, doc);
```

This pushes the action onto the UI thread which will be executed synchronously, and doesn't cause issues if you call it from the UI thread itself.